# Parse 2-dimensional array retrieved as string from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays

I am building an array of data that is being retrieved from the cells of a table. The resulting array looks something like this:

```
[["","","",""],["","9/2/14","","9/17/14"],["","","89ol",""],["","687k","","9-0["p/"],["","245g","245g","356h"],["","","",""],["","","4j6","467j"],["","","9/9/14",""]]
```

I'm saving the data to a MySQL database as a string in one field. I now need to retrieve that data and iterate through it to repopulate the table.

I'm getting the data to an $.ajax function as a string in the above format.

How can I get the individual cell data to populate the cells properly?

**UPDATE:**
Here's the php code I'm using to retrieve the data:

```
$queryGetUserTaskNotes = "SELECT userProgressNotes FROM userProgress WHERE userProgressUserID = $userID AND userProgressSiteID = $siteID and userProgressNotesTable = '" . $taskTableID . "'";
$resultGetUserTaskNotes = @mysqli_query($dbc,$queryGetUserTaskNotes);
if ($resultGetUserTaskNotes) {
    $taskNotes = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultGetUserTaskNotes);
    echo $taskNotes['userProgressNotes'];
}
```

Here's how I'm getting the data from the php script

```
function GetTaskNotes(siteID,tableID) {
$.ajax({
            url: 'script.php',
    data: {getTaskNotes:'true', userID:userID, siteID:siteID, tableID:tableID},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log('GetTaskNotes data: ' + data);
    }
});
}
```

As for what I've tried so far, I've been working with how to parse the string on the js side in the success function. JSON.parse(data) didn't work and frankly, I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried.

Comment: If the down vote was for lack of information, I've updated the post to explain more about how and what I'm doing.

Comment: I did not DV, just asked you to share what you had tried.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't directed at you specifically, @JayBlanchard

Comment: this data appears to be json, you probably can directly access the content by `data[0][0]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very special needs in terms of performance/logic, I would say it would be better to use a hash of name/value pairs (a.k.a an object) where the names in the hash correspond to actual fields in the database. That being said, lets say for the sake of argument that the arrays are populated by .push() calls, in which case a simple nested for loop should work:

```
'use strict';
var array = JSON.parse(string);
var cell, row, i, j;
var table = document.createElement('table');
for (i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    row = document.createElement('tr');
    for (j=0; j < array[i].length; ++j) {
        cell = document.createElement('td');
        cell.innerHTML = array[i][j];
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    table.appendChild(row);
}
document.appendChild(table);
```

Where `string` is the string you get back from the DB when its time to repopulate.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse earlier, but for some crazy reason it didn't work for me. I ran your code on a test page using the string array in my post and it worked fine (got an error on the document.appendChild(table) line, but I know I can access the data now). THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

I think the steps here for you are going to be:

In PHP, provide a URL that JS can do a GET against that will return the data. The way that is structured and looks will depend somewhat on what framework (if any) that you're using. Be sure to return that data as JSON using a built in PHP JSON encode method.

In JS, do a GET like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your url here',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

In your success function, I assume you'll handle iterating over your object and inserting it into the DOM. I would look at jQuery's $.each() method for that. When it comes to "populating the cells properly", it'd be helpful to see your HTML and JS in a jsFiddle or something.

Good luck!

References:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/